# How to set dijit.form.radiobutton readonly mode

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have a radiobutton which I need to set as readonly. In readonly mode, it should show selected status but not respond to hover or click. The dojo documentation is a bit sparse in this regard. Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add Disabled to your Tag:

```
<input data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/CheckBox" type="checkbox" disabled />
```